# How to fix a merge if (quote) args problem in R?

Tags: r

I need to merge multiple excel files. They share two columns but there aren't observations for those columns in all the files.

I want to merge them by Office and Machine columns.

The code

```r
library(readxl)
library(tidyr)

setwd("...")

my_files <- list.files(pattern = "*.xlsx")
my_files

mba <-lapply(my_files, function (i){
  x=read_excel(i, sheet = "1")
  x$file=i
  x
})

mba[[1]]
mba <-do.call("merge.data.frame", mba, list(by=c("Office", "Machine")))
mba
```

I use that code but there is an error:

> *Error in if (quote) args <- lapply(args, enquote) :
> argumento no interpetable como lógico*

I am not sure how to fix it.

Comment: You are right! Is R. Sorry! I already edit the question.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).